# How to concantenate specific lines using awk?

Tags: awk, concatenation

I am looking to learn how to concatenate multiple columns in linux. I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
gene    match_type  drug                sources      pmids
ABO     Definite    CHEMBL50267         DrugBank     17139284|17016423
ABO     Definite    URIDINE_DIPHOSPHATE TdgClinicalTrial     17139284|17016423
ABO     Definite    CHEMBL439009        DrugBank     12972418
ABO     Definite    CHEMBL1232343       DrugBank       NA
ABO     Definite    CHEMBL503075        DrugBank       NA
```

I am trying to bring this into one row (concatenating the drug column, the sources column and the pmids column) to look like:

```
gene    match_type  drug                                                                         sources                                           pmids
ABO     Definite    CHEMBL1232343 CHEMBL439009 CHEMBL50267 CHEMBL503075 URIDINE_DIPHOSPHATE NA  DrugBank TdgClinicalTrial DrugBank DrugBank DrugBank    0 12972418 17139284|17016423  17139284|17016423 NA NA
```

I have looked into using awk with if statements but I am not really sure where to start with this, any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worried about spacing part of headers then please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
    a[$1 OFS i]=(a[$1 OFS i]?a[$1 OFS i] FS $i:$i)
  }
  b[$1]=$2
}
END{
  for(j in b){
    printf j OFS b[j] OFS
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
       printf("%s %s",a[j OFS i],i==NF?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation of above command now.

```
awk '                                                      ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==1{                                                    ##Checking condition if FNR==1 means first line of Input_file then do following.
  print                                                    ##Printing the current line.
  next                                                     ##next will skip all further lines from here.
}                                                          ##Closing FNR==1 condition BLOCK here.
{                                                          ##Starting BLOCK which will be executed apart from 1st line of Input_file.
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){                                      ##tarting a for loop which starts from i=3 to till value of NF.
    a[$1 OFS i]=(a[$1 OFS i]?a[$1 OFS i] FS $i:$i)         ##Creating an array a whose index is $1 and i value and concatenating its value with its own value.
  }                                                        ##Closing for loop block here.
  b[$1]=$2                                                 ##Creating array named b whose index is $1 and value is $2.
}                                                          ##Closing block for, for loop now.
END{                                                       ##Starting END block of awk program here.
  for(j in b){                                             ##Traversing through array b here.
    printf j OFS b[j] OFS                                  ##Printing value of j OFS value of b[j] and OFS value here.
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){                                    ##Starting for loop from i=3 to value of NF here.
       printf("%s %s",a[j OFS i],i==NF?ORS:OFS)            ##Printing value of a[j OFS i] along with either space or new line. New line should be printed when loop reached its maximum value.
    }                                                      ##Closing block for inner for loop here.
  }                                                        ##Closing block for outer for loop here.
}' OFS="\t"   file                                         ##Setting OFS as TAB here and mentioning Input_file name here.
```